# cannot overwrite hive scratchdir via ambari

Tags: hadoop, hive

I changed the value of `hive.exec.scratchdir` to `/customdirname` via Ambari but the default folder `/tmp/hive` continues to be used, why?

Is there a way to fix this so that hive only uses the modified directory?

Comment: Are you talking about HDFS or client (local) temp directory? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Configuration#AdminManualConfiguration-TemporaryFolders

Comment: I'm talking about HDFS

Comment: Does `/customdirname` exist and does `hive` have RW permissions to it?

Comment: yes, /customdirname exist and has the right rights 777

Comment: Next question - you have `hive.exec.scratchdir` set in `hive-site.xml` used by HiveServer2, and HS2 was restarted? Sorry :)

Comment: Yes, I do. hive.exec.scratchdir is set in hive-site.xml used by HiveServer2, and HS2 was restarted

Comment: Then the only thing left is to check HS2 log close to startup to see if anything there may indicate why this dir is not used.

Comment: I may have expressed myself badly. The problem is that the 2 directories are used
Sometimes the custom dir is used and often dthe default dir is used

Comment: Please, any help ?

Comment: Not sure, maybe some of the clients didnt get the updated `hive-site.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having some instances of both directories being used, you can just symlink `/tmp/hive` to `/customdir`

Comment: Please do not ask questions in the answers.